# Oracle Encrypt Method Similar to MySql

Tags: oracle

Is there any function in oracle similar to `encrypt/decrypt`  functions in MySql?
If not how to proceed in oracle ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at DBMS_CRYPTO

It has methods to encrypt and decrypt data built in.  Better than writing your own.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm